# Es posible descargar archivos desde Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Estoy teniendo problemas intentando descargar archivos desde Flask, he hecho lo siguiente, envio un body json `{"text":"Google text to speech test"}` a mi endpoint, realizo la funcion luego intento descargarlo, He ocupado el metodo  `send_file()`.

ejemplo:

```
@app.route('/tts', methods=['POST'])
def tts():
    try:
        text = request.json['text']
        user = Usermessages(_messages=text)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        tts = gTTS(text)
        uuidOne = uuid.uuid1()
        downloadfile = f'{uuidOne}.mp3'
        tts.save(f"{downloadfile}")
        os.system(f"start {downloadfile}")
        return send_file(f"{downloadfile}", as_attachment=True), 200
    except:
        raise
```

Y tambien he intentado el metodo `send_from_directory()`, pero sigue sin retornar el arhcivo:

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './'
    @app.route('/tts', methods=['POST'])
    def tts():
        try:
            text = request.json['text']
            user = Usermessages(_messages=text)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            tts = gTTS(text)
            uuidOne = uuid.uuid1()
            downloadfile = f'{uuidOne}.mp3'
            tts.save(f"{downloadfile}")
            os.system(f"start {downloadfile}")
            return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],downloadfile,as_attachment=True)
        except:
            raise
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta debes traducirla al castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Hola Andres, es muy importante revisar los enlaces que te comparte Mauricio, saludos.